# XCode 4 and iOS 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, firmware

I've installed XCode4 and I need to build for iOS 4.2.1 is there a possibility to install the "old" firmware 4.2.1 and build against it?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to target 4.2 version with XCode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253695/how-to-target-4-2-version-with-xcode-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it you can only use a 4.3 Base SDK but can target also older OSes like 4.2.1 or whatever. So no need to install old firmwares.

Actually it wouldn't make sense any other way. I have a older iPod Touch which can only be upgraded to 4.2.1, so it has to be programmed targeted for 4.2.1 using the same toolset.

Comment: After some googleing I found that the so called "Development Target" is the corresponding setting. thx.

Comment: In Xcode 4.0.1, the setting is called "Deployment Target", and it is available in the info tab of the PROJECT settings panel and the summary tab of the TARGETS panel.