# Get iPhone app to iPod from remote machine for testing

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, remote-debugging

My problem is - I work on a remote mac through Remote Desktop Connection - from a windows host.
I have my app ready on remote mac.
I have my iPod with me, connected to my windows host.
How do I get this app onto my device for testing purpose?

My access to the mac is through RDP.
I edited the rdp connection to allow local usb access to my remote mac, (remotely) hoping that my mac would see it as a device. But it didn't.

Is there any way it would see my iPod?
(I already read [this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices) and it requires mac-to-ipod direct connection.)

Or is there any other path I can get my app package on my device for testing through windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you will have to add your iPod to the developer portal if you haven't already. Next you can do a build and archive which will export your app into organiser. Click on the app version in organiser and click the distribute button and make sure you select ad-hoc distribution. This will give you a .app packaged version of your app which can then be sent across to your windows machine from your remote desktop where you can then drag it into iTunes and install it on your iPod.

If you are testing lots of different builds of your app over a short space of time then i would suggest using test flight, which can be found easily when googled. It allows you to upload versions of your app through and ad-hoc .app package which ca then be installed across all your devices using the test flight app on your phone. I would only recommend doing this if you are doing lots of builds and testing on lots of devices though.

Hope this helps

Sam

Comment: Many thanks for the quick and direct response! As for test flight, does it also require the developer program registration?

Comment: Currently, it shows archive as grayed out option. Does that mean I need to get it to developer portal? Does it require paid registration or free account does OK?

Comment: In other words, which apple page to visit to register my iphone from my windows box? (because as you know, I can't access it from remote mac)

Comment: YOu need to go to the developers section and go to the provisioning portal.Firstly add your device under the device tab, you only need the the unique identifier for your phone which can be found by plugging your device into your windows machine and opening it up in iTunes and look at the phone info in there. Add the device to the portal with the unique identifier. Then you need to create an ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile which can be found in the distribution tab under the provisioning tab. Download this to your remote mac change the provisioning setting in Xcode to your....

Comment: new certificate, and ad-hoc will now be enabled if these steps are followed correctly

Comment: thanksk shoughton123, for detailed answer. However I found out after logging in that IDP is not directly purchasable from my country (India). They require some form to be faxed that they will consider at ease later on. I am quite in hurry but don't know what to do now, except sit until they approve. And as it turns out, there is no way for testing other than developer account worth $99, I guess.

Comment: Well yeah obviously I just assumed you would have a developers account, you can not test on a real device, get access to any beta software or release any apps to the app store with a developers account. Basically if you want to make an app you need a developers account.

Comment: OK, I got registered in dev program. Followed all the steps: Code-signed using new provisioning profile, Got the archive using Archive command, and executed 'Distribute' to generate the ipa. This ipa, I imported into my itunes (on windows box), and synced the ipod. Nothing syncs still. I cannot get this app onto my ipod yet. (as said, I kept development target 4.2 which is less than what my ipod has.) What am I missing here?

Comment: Also followed steps about .mobileprovision (as described on: http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution?zip_file=AppName.app.AdHoc.ipa) - yet I am unable to get it on my ipod. This ipod I registered on apple portal to obtain my developer profile. Any clues, anyone?

Comment: OK, finally hit the root of the issue via testflight. Uploaded my ipa over testflight. When I tried installing over iphone internet, it produced this error: This device is running 4.2.1, which is less than the required version (5.1) for this build. Upgrade your iOS install. (I have built this build on archive scheme->iOS Device rather than iPhone simulator 5.1). My project base sdk tells iOS 5.1 as I don't see any other option there. My project deployment target is set to 4.2. What can I do? Please help, this is getting on my nerve...

Comment: Final update: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562952/xcode-4-and-ios-4-2-1 - Archived - but got error - storyboard not supported in iOS 4.2. Once again, I followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781483/ios5-storyboard-error-storyboards-are-unavailable-on-ios-4-3-and-prior and successfully archived it. Got it through testflightapp.com, installed on my ipod touch with iOS 4.2.1. Got to see the app icon too. But when tried to launch it, the screen was blank! Just can't get nearer! (seems if no one faced hurdles like I did over here, should I start another question thread?)

Comment: If you trying to use storyboards on a device running IOS 4.2 its never going to work. It also never going to work if your device is not a valid provisioning device without a valid provisioning certificate and without a valid developer account!

Comment: Didn't I say I have developer account with all membership setup? I followed all the steps to get the provisioning profile too. But still for some or other reasons it doesn't work. Yes, I got around the storyboards issue as I said in my last comment. And now the blank screen.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help so far! To summarize, I have opened a new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570388/xcode-4-3-3-issues-while-testing-on-ios-4-2-1 - still waiting for help...