# iPhone 3G XCode Development for 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, jailbreak, iphone-3g

I've managed to resurrect my old iPhone 3G which runs 4.2.1. Can I still develop using XCode on this phone? I would ideally like to use it for learning Obj-C without paying for the Developers Program, Jailbreaking just to test my apps.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is feasible but you will not be able to use xcode the latest xcode 4.5 with it because it supports ios 4.3 and later. You would be able to use lower versions of xcode for 4.2.1 . The latest release notes indicates 4.2.1 and lower will not be supported, we now have to use 2 version of Xcode to develop when supporting older devices.

Please go through

[Old Xcode](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132405/if-you-need-the-old-xcode-421-read-this)

[Xcode 4.5 and iOS 4.2.1 incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463195/xcode-4-5-and-ios-4-2-1-incompatibility)

[XCode 4 and iOS 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562952/xcode-4-and-ios-4-2-1)

Comment: Do I need to use XCode for Jailbroken Apps? It would be a lot more easier for me to write c code by using a vim/c compiler combo.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the answer I posted, which is the second link in your list, it does explain how you **can** use Xcode 4.5 to do this.  You just have to copy an older SDK (e.g. from Xcode 4.4) into the Xcode 4.5 SDK folder, and choose the iOS 5 SDK to get `armv6` support.  Polyglot, yes, you can build jailbreak apps without Xcode at all, but I personally think it's harder to do so (unless you don't have a Mac at all).